# What do you call a person who takes interest in analyzing people's handwritings?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, handwriting

Is there any single word that is used to indicate a person who reads the psychological aspect of people's handwritings (like what they believe and what type of people they are, etc.)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The study of handwriting is called **graphology**, and the person who is inclined to do so is a **graphologist**.

Comment: Just so you all know, my phrenologist says that graphology is a questionable science...

Comment: So does our local homeopath.

Answer (score 5):

That would be a *graphologist*.

Comment: Gotcha! (by 12 seconds)

Comment: I would have been first, but SE wouldn't allow me to post my single-word answer :)

Comment: I like your answer better though, so +1

Comment: That was a good sporting spirit. +1 :)